# Is there any good way to append data horizontally or widely based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, reshape

```
<pre> df1
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id  | rc  | fq  | mt  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 | a   |   3 |  13 |
|   2 | b   |   2 |  31 |
|   3 | c   |   4 |  23 |
|   4 | d   |   1 |   7 |
|   5 | e   |   6 |   9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+


<pre> df2
+----+---------+----------+
| id | keyword | location |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | james   | (1,3)    |
| 1  | john    | (2,3)    |
| 2  | daniel  | (3,9)    |
| 3  | peter   | (5,2)    |
| 3  | hugh    | (7,1)    |
| 3  | kevin   | (2,1)    |
| 4  | jack    | (0,8)    |
| 5  | chris   | (4,2)    |
| 5  | lisa    | (9,0)    |
| …  | …       | …        |
| …  | …       | …        |
| …  | …       | …        |
+----+---------+----------+

<pre> df3
+----+----+----+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---+-----------+------------+
| id | rc | fq | mt | keyword1 | location1 | keyword2 | location2 | keyword3 | location3 | … | keyword_n | location_n |
+----+----+----+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---+-----------+------------+
|  1 | a  |  3 | 13 | james    | (1,3)     | john     | (2,3)     |          |           | … |           |            |
|  2 | b  |  2 | 31 | daniel   | (3,9)     |          |           |          |           | … |           |            |
|  3 | c  |  4 | 23 | peter    | (5,2)     | hugh     | (7,1)     | kevin    | (2,1)     | … |           |            |
|  4 | d  |  1 |  7 | jack     | (0,8)     |          |           |          |           | … |           |            |
|  5 | e  |  6 |  9 | chris    | (4,2)     | lisa     | (9,0)     |          |           | … |           |            |
|    |    |    |    |          |           |          |           |          |           | … |           |            |
|    |    |    |    |          |           |          |           |          |           | … |           |            |
|    |    |    |    |          |           |          |           |          |           | … |           |            |
+----+----+----+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---+-----------+------------+
```

[I have a wide form pandas dataframe with 'id' column indicating unique values of each row.][df1]

[And also have df2 with 'id', 'keyword' and 'location' columns. Ids in df2 are originated from df1 so df1 and df2 share the 'id' values.][df2]

[Lastly, this df3 is desired output out of df1 and df2. If ids in df2 have the same value with the in df1, values in 'keyword' and 'location' columns should be appended widely or horizontally creating new columns.][df3]

Hi all,

I attached pictures for better explanation. (Please check those out!)

I tried loc, concat, merge, and pivot_table etc but could not figure it out.
Could please anyone give some advice on this one?

Thanks!

- Sorry for attaching pictures rather than inserting ascii table. Pictures deleted!

Comment: You need 4 spaces for code block - then formating of question is nice - I do it for `df1`

Comment: @jezrael Thank you! Edited :)

Comment: You are welcome! Can you check answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `id` and counter created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
- reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
- sort second level of Multiindex in columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
- flatten columns by `map` with `join`
- [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to first `DataFrame`

---

```
s = df2.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df2 = df2.set_index(['id', s]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)

df = df1.join(df2, on='id')
print (df)
   id CC  fq  mt keyword1 location1 keyword2 location2 keyword3 location3
0   1  a   3  13    james     (1,3)     john     (2,3)     None      None
1   2  b   2  31   daniel     (3,9)     None      None     None      None
2   3  c   4  23    peter     (5,2)     hugh     (7,1)    kevin     (2,1)
3   4  d   1   7     jack     (0,8)     None      None     None      None
4   5  e   6   9    chris     (4,2)     lisa     (9,0)     None      None
```

Comment: Not only it works perfectly but also I could learn something(e.g.cumcount()) I've never tried! Thanks! (I upvoted your answer but it didn't show up cause of my low reputation :\)